# To prove $g \circ f=I_U$ and $g$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I need to provde the proofs for the below :-

(1) On a set $U$ two functions are defined as $f,g: U \rightarrow U $, Given is that $f \circ g=I_U$ and $g$ is surjective.
Prove that $g \circ f=I_U$

(2) Give an example of a set $U$ and two functions  $f,g: U \rightarrow U $, for which $f \circ g=I_U$ and $g \circ f \neq I_U$

Can anyone help me by providing a hint for(1) and an example for (2)

Comment: You seem to be missing some text about $g$ at the end of (1).

Comment: Is $I_U$ just a subset of $U$ or is it an identity element or something other than a subset?

Comment: @marshalcraft $I_U$ is (clearly) the identity function on $U$.

Comment: Well ok It wasn't so clear to me being as we only have a set $U$ and no binary operation for the identity.

Comment: An example for 2 would be any sets with function $g:U \to I_U$ and $f:I_U \to X$ such that $I_U \cap X = \emptyset$. Specifically $f$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: It's the composition of two functions from $U$ to $U$, so it's a function from $U$ to $U$. "Binary operation for the identity"? No comprende.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

From $f\circ g=I_U$, what can you deduce for $g$ and for $f$?

Comment: one of the $f$ or $g$ is having inverse. Is this?

Comment: That would be too simple. If $f\circ g$ is injective, what can you say of $g$?

Comment: g is injective too

Comment: And it's surjective by hypothesis. So…?

Comment: So then $f \circ g $ is bijective as well. so then can I proceed like this $f \circ g(x)= x$   ;  $f(x)= g^{^-1}(x)$   ;  $g \circ f= I_U$

Comment: Also  one point is not clear to me, how $f\circ g=I_U$ means  $f\circ g$ is injective

Comment: The identity map is injective – even bijective.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, but the proof which I gave in the previous comment , is that correct ?

Comment: There's a small problem at the start: you can conclude that $g$ is bijective (for $f\circ g$, it does not give an supplementary information), hence it has an inverse. The rest is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help and feedback. Its clear to me now.

Comment: do you know any example for satisfying  $f \circ g=I_U$  and $g \circ f \neq I_U$

Answer (score 0):

(1) Show that $g$ is injective. If $x, y \in U$ and $x\neq y$, then $x = f(g(x)) \neq f(g(y)) = y$. Can $g(x)$ equal $g(y)$?

(2) Let $U = \mathbb{N}, g(n) = 2n, f(m) = \lfloor{m/2}\rfloor$.

Comment: I am not able to get your example, can you just help me to understand it, or is there any other simple example

Comment: No, there aren't any simpler examples. $f\circ g = I_U$ means that $g$ is an injection. If $U$ is finite then every injection is a surjection (& thus is a bijection), so you need $U$ to be infinite for the counterexample of (2). 
What is so obscure about those two functions from ints to ints i described? In case it's the notation (perhaps you don't know the "floor" function), $f(2n) = n, f(2n+1) = n$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $f$ and $g$ map $U \to U$ and $g$ a surjection we know $g$ maps to every element in $U$. If $U$ is finite then $g$ a bijection. Intuitively in order for $g$ to map to every single element in $U$ (if same cardnality) every element must be "used". It is easy to see then that $f$ must map to one element. You can prove this by proof by contradiction and assume that $f$ maps to more than one elements and arrive at a contradiction.

Then if for all $x \in U$ and $f$ defined by $f(x)=c$ where $c$ a constant and an element of $U$, then $g \circ f \to c$. A little more work is needed to show that $c=I_U$